# Python3 Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to connect to my database with sqlAlchemy and get the error `Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql`. The script worked before and I didn't change anything, tho I can't connect to the db.

I'm importing the libraries:

```
#from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, MetaData
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import *
from pybigquery.api import ApiClient
```

My connection:

```
# Database parameter
host = "127.0.0.1"         
user = "someUser"          
passwd = "somePassword"    
database = "ucb-pvapp"     

# Database connection
db=pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        user=user,
        passwd=passwd,
        db=database,
        autocommit=True)

engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{database}')
cursor=db.cursor()
```

sqlAlchemy and pymysql are installed.

Using Ubuntu 20.04, python 3.8.5 and sqlalchemy Version 1.3.12.
Complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pv.py", line 131, in <module>
    engine = create_engine(f'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{passwd}@{host}/{database}')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/__init__.py", line 500, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 61, in create
    entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/url.py", line 172, in _get_entrypoint
    cls = registry.load(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 268, in load
    raise exc.NoSuchModuleError(
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, just simply removing "pymysql" and installing it again solved the problem - whatever it was. It's that easy sometimes.

Comment: I ended up having to purge my virtual env and reinstall all packages. Python 3.6.8, pymysql == 1.0.2, sqlalchemy == 1.3.24

Answer (score 2):

Hello I also ran into the same problem, I tried uninstalling pymysql and reinstalling but that didn't work. However, adding a simple `import pymysql` statement solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you need to do `from sqlalchemy import *` ?
You need to be more specific:

- which python and sqlalchemy version are you using?

Comment: No, I'm not, just tried it cause it was mentioned in another post.
I'm using python 3.8.5 and sqlalchemyVersion 1.3.12. Currently I'm using
`from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, Integer, String, DateTime, Float, MetaData` like before.